# SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations Fails with SSL_ERROR_NONE

Tags: c++, openssl

I've searched high and low and have not found an explanation of this problem.

I'm running the following

```
int ret = 0;
ERR_clear_error();
ret = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations( ctx_, "f:\\50\\server\\SSLCACertificateFile.pem", NULL );
```

I get a ret value of 1, which is an error.  I then check the error queue.

```
int err = SSL_get_error( con_, ret );
```

The err value returned is zero.  That value is associated with the error: `SSL_ERROR_NONE`.

`SSL_ERROR_NONE` means that the function actually succeeded.

Can I trust that the `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` function really did run successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man  SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations

```
RETURN VALUES

   The following return values can occur:

   0   The operation failed because CAfile and CApath are NULL or the processing at one of the locations specified failed. Check the error stack to find out the
       reason.

   1   The operation succeeded.
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir,

When I go to Openssl.org here:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html#return_values

I see the following information for Return Values:

The following return values can occur:

1 The operation failed because CAfile and CApath are NULL or the processing at one of the locations specified failed. Check the error stack to find out the reason.

2 The operation succeeded.

I wonder which is correct man or openssl itself?

Comment: You can look source files and find definition in ssl/ssl_lib.c which calls X509_STORE_load_locations from crypto/x509/x509_d2.c which returns  1 on success:https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/ssl/ssl_lib.c#L3229    https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/x509/x509_d2.c#L83

Comment: Also you can look source for the forementioned web version of the man page and there is no 1 and 2 return values defined: there goes HTML list which is numbered from 1, not from zero.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks very much, Vladimir.  Last time that I blindly trust documentation.  You have taught me a new method of debugging.  I have done this in the past, but it never dawned on me in this case, as I had documentation.  Lesson learned.  Thanks again.

Comment: Its a very rare exception. You don't have to be paranoid. 'Trust but verify' as proverb says.