# C client with OpenSSL + Java server : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, jsse, tls1.2

I have Java SSL socket and c client with OpenSSL (java clients works ok with this Java server). Handshake fails and i'm getting Java exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1904)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:269)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(ServerHandshaker.java:901)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:629)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:167)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:901)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:837)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:889)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
    at EchoServer.main(EchoServer.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Here is how server SSL socket is created:

```
public class EchoServer {
    public static void main(String[] arstring) {
        try {
            final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

            final InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/Path/mySrvKeystore.jks");
            keyStore.load(is, "123456".toCharArray());
            final KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory .getDefaultAlgorithm());
            kmf.init(keyStore, "123456".toCharArray());
            final TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory .getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(keyStore);

            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), new java.security.SecureRandom());

            SSLServerSocketFactory sslserversocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLServerSocket sslserversocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslserversocketfactory.createServerSocket(9997);
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslserversocket.accept();
            sslsocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(sc.getServerSocketFactory().getSupportedCipherSuites());

            InputStream inputstream = sslsocket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

            String string = null;
            while ((string = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(string);
                System.out.flush();
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

C client:

```
BIO *certbio = NULL;
BIO *outbio = NULL;
SSL_METHOD *ssl_method;
SSL_CTX *ssl_ctx;
SSL *ssl;

int sd;

// These function calls initialize openssl for correct work.
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
ERR_load_BIO_strings();
ERR_load_crypto_strings();
SSL_load_error_strings();

// Create the Input/Output BIO's.
certbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
outbio  = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);

// initialize SSL library and register algorithms
if(SSL_library_init() < 0)
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Could not initialize the OpenSSL library !\n");

ssl_method = (SSL_METHOD*)TLSv1_2_method();

// Try to create a new SSL context
if ( (ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(ssl_method)) == NULL)
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Unable to create a new SSL context structure.\n");

// flags
SSL_CTX_set_options(ssl_ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION | SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE);

// Create new SSL connection state object
ssl = SSL_new(ssl_ctx);

// Make the underlying TCP socket connection
struct sockaddr_in address;

memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons(port);

const char *dest_url = this->host.c_str();

address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(dest_url);
address.sin_port = htons(port);

sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
int connect_result = ::connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address));
if (connect_result != 0) {
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Failed to connect over TCP with error %i\n", connect_result);
    throw IOException("Connection refused");
} else {
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Successfully made the TCP connection to: %s:%i\n", dest_url, port);
}

// Attach the SSL session to the socket descriptor
SSL_set_fd(ssl, sd);

// Try to SSL-connect here, returns 1 for success
int ssl_connect_result = SSL_connect(ssl);
if (ssl_connect_result != 1)
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Error: Could not build a SSL session to: %s:%i with error %i\n", dest_url, port, ssl_connect_result);
else
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Successfully enabled SSL/TLS session to: %s\n", dest_url);
```

Here is output on client side:

> Error: Could not build a SSL session to: 127.0.0.1:9997 with error -1

*Update 1*

```
int ssl_connect_result = SSL_connect(ssl);
if (ssl_connect_result != 1) {
    int error_code = SSL_get_error(ssl, ssl_connect_result); // =1
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Error: Could not build a SSL session to: %s:%i with error %i (%i)\n", dest_url, port, ssl_connect_result, error_code);
} else {
    BIO_printf(outbio, "Successfully enabled SSL/TLS session to: %s\n", dest_url);
}
```

And the output is:

> Error: Could not build a SSL session to: 127.0.0.1:9997 with error -1 (1)

*Update 2*

I forgot to note that I'm using self-signed certificate, generated by `keytool` from JDK.

*Update 3*

I've noted i missed some lines and I've added:

```
OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers();
OpenSSL_add_all_digests();
```

but still no luck - getting the same error -1.

*Update 4*

Here is Java client which is accepted by the server code above:

```
SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(ip, port);
sslsocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslsocketfactory.getSupportedCipherSuites());

InputStream inputstream = System.in;
InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

OutputStream outputstream = sslsocket.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter outputstreamwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream);
String string = null;

outputstreamwriter.write("hello");
outputstreamwriter.flush();

while ((string = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
    outputstreamwriter.write(string);
    outputstreamwriter.flush();
}
sslsocket.close();
```

I've checked that I can't see plain data in packets intercepted in the network so it does perform some data encryption.

Comment: You need to call `SSL_get_error()` after the `SSL_connect()` to get the cause of your problem. I don't really remember any issues  with blocking sockets, but with non-blocking ones you had to call `SSL_connect()` many times, to allow it to perform its many writes and reads. More specifically, while the error was `SSL_want_read` or `SSL_want_write`. Oh, and you forgot the `SSL_set_connect_state()`, so OpenSSL knows you're using a client here.

Comment: according to the doc(https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_set_connect_state.html) "When using the SSL_connect or SSL_accept routines, the correct handshake routines are automatically set.". Do i have to invoke `SSL_set_connect_state ` even if i invoke `SSL_connect`? I will try to get more info using `SSL_get_error `

Comment: Updated the question with `SSL_get_error ` result, which is `1` (SSL_ERROR_SSL)

Comment: Get rid of the `setEnabledCipherSuites()` call. It's insecure to use all the supoorted cipher suites.

Comment: Have you tried connecting your C client to an OpenSSL sample server? Using `openssl s_server` ? With and without certificate requirement? It may prove very helplful, especially with `-msg` and `-debug`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that Java server accepts a Java client either, unless the Java client similarly does `.setEnabledCipherSuites (all-supported)` -- if so it is using an anonymous (unauthenticated) ciphersuite that is not secure against active attack, and although many people are still stuck in the passive-only threat model of about 1980, today active attacks are common. That is why JSSE's default cipherlist excludes anonymous ciphers -- unless you override it. And why OpenSSL's default cipherlist also excludes them -- which you didn't override.

**(add)** To explain in smaller words, anonymous ciphersuites ARE encrypted (with a few exceptions not relevant here because they are never preferred) but NOT authenticated. The word "unauthenticated" means "not authenticated"; it does not mean "not encrypted". The word "unencrypted" is used to mean "not encrypted". "Not encrypted" means something that just looks at the channel, like Wireshark, can see the plaintext. "Not authenticated" means an attacker who intercepts (possibly diverts) your traffic can cause you to establish your "secure" session with the attacker in the middle, and they can decrypt your data, copy and/or change it as they wish, re-encrypt it, and send it on, and you will think it is correct and private when it isn't. Google or search here (I think mostly security.SE and superuser) for things like "man in the middle attack", "ARP spoof", "MAC spoof", "DNS poisoning", "BGP attack", etc.

The immediate problem is **you aren't using the keystore**. You create an `SSLContext` with key and trust managers from it, but then you create the socket from `SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault()` which doesn't use the context. **Use `sc.getServerSocketFactory()` instead.**

**(add) why?** Every `SSLSocket` (and `SSLServerSocket`) is linked to an `SSLContext` which among other things controls the privatekey(s) and certificate(s) or chain(s) used and certificates trusted. (SSL/TLS connections normally authenticate the server only, so in practice the server only needs a key-and-chain, and the client only needs the root cert, but Java uses the same keystore file format for both and it's easy to just code both.) Since your code has set the particular `SSLContext sc` to contain a suitable key-and-cert, `sc.getServerSocketFactory()` creates a factory which creates an `SSLServerSocket` which in turn creates an `SSLSocket` (for each connection if more than one) which uses that key-and-(as long as the client's supported cipher list allows it, and here it does).

**(add)** `SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault()` creates a factory, and thus sockets, using the *default* SSL context, which by default contains **NO key-and-chain**, although you can change this with system properties as described in the documentation cleverly hidden at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html . As a result it cannot negotiate a ciphersuite that is authenticated. Since both Java and OpenSSL by default disable unauthenticated ciphersuites, this is why you get "no cipher suites in common" unless you `.setEnabled` to include the unauthenticated and insecure ciphersuites in Java, and still get it for OpenSSL client since you didn't do anything to enable unauthenticated and insecure ciphersuites there.

**(add)** If you look carefully at your Wireshark trace, you will see in the `ServerHello` that the selected ciphersuite uses `DH_anon` or `ECDH_anon` key exchange -- "anon" is an abbreviation for "anonymous" which means "not authenticated" as explained above -- and there is no `Certificate` message from the server, and (less obvious unless you know it) the `ServerKeyExchange` data is not signed. 
Also I predict if you have your Java client check `sslsocket.getSession().getCipherSuite()` and/or `sslsocket.getSession().getPeerCertificates()` after the handshake is done, which since you don't do it explicitly will be on the first socket-level I/O which will be the `outputstreamwriter.flush()`, you will see the anonymous ciphersuite, and no peer cert (it throws PeerNotAuthenticated).

Other points:

(1) In general whenever you get `SSL_ERROR` from `SSL_get_error()`, or any error return from lower level routines like `EVP_*` and `BIO_*`, you should use the `ERR_*` routines to get details of the error and log/display them; see https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#PROG6 and https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/ERR_print_errors.html et amici. Especially since you HAVE loaded the error strings, thus avoiding https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#PROG7 . In this case however you already know enough from the server side, so client side details aren't needed.

(2) You don't need `_add_all_ciphers` and `_add_all_digests`, they are included in `_add_all_algorithms`.

(3) `OP_NO_SSLv2` and `3` have no effect on `TLSv1_2_method` and `OP_SERVER_CIPHER_PREFERENCE` has no effect on a client. (They do no harm, they are just useless and possibly confusing.)

(4) Once you get past the cipher negotiation, the OpenSSL **client will need the root cert** for the server; since you intend to use a self-signed cert (once you fix the server to use the keystore at all) that cert is its own root. In 1.0.2 (not earlier) you could also use a non-root trust anchor, but not by default and you don't have one anyway. I assume `certbio` was intended for this, but you never open it on an actual file or do anything else with it, and anyway the `SSL` library cannot use a BIO for its truststore. You have three choices:

- put the cert(s) in a file, or a directory using special hash names, and pass the file and/or directory name(s) to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations`. If you only want one root (your own) using the `CAfile` option is easier.
- put or add the cert(s) to the default file or hashed directory determined by your OpenSSL library compilation and call `SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths`; this is commonly something like `/etc/pki` or `/var/ssl`. If you want to use the same cert(s) for multiple programs or for commandline `openssl` this shared location is usually easier.
- use the BIO and/or other means to (open and) *read* the cert(s) into memory, build your own `X509_STORE` containing them, and put that in your `SSL_CTX`. This is more complicated, so I won't expand on it unless you want to.

(5) Your `dest_url` is (at least in this case?) an address string, not a URL; those are different though related things and thinking they are the same will cause you lots more problems. For most programs it is better to handle a host *name* string with classic `gethostbyname` and fall back to `inet_addr`, or better the "new" (since 1990s) `getaddrinfo` which can handle both name and address strings and both IPv4 and v6 (also new since 1990s but finally gaining traction). At the very least you should check for `inet_addr` returning `INADDR_NONE` indicating it failed.

Comment: First, thank you for such detailed answer. My comments are: 1) Java lcient can actually connect to that Java SSL socket and i can see no plain data in the packets. 2) i've checked and i can confirm `sc.getServerSocketFactory()` and `SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault()` return different objects. What's the difference? I believe that sc.get .. should return factory that does encryption actually so why `SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault()` exist in the world since every connection relates to some SSL context and there is no `default`? 3) I'm going to check another points you've mentioned. Thanks

Comment: i've commented `setEnabledCipherSuits` in both java server and client and that can't communicate any more (`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common` on server side and `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure` on client side. and yes - i'm creating server socket factory using `sc.getServerSocketFactory()` on server side). What's wrong? After that i will move to c client

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
> ```

Java used to do two thing with code similar to this:

- enable SSLv3
- disable TLS 1.1 and 1.2

... Even though you called out TLS. Effectively, all you could get was a `SSLContext` with SSLv3 and TLS 1.0 (unless you were willing to do more work). It may not be the case anymore, but it would explain the error you are seeing (especially if your are using Java 7 or 8).

You need to do more work in Java to get "TLS 1.0 or above" and "just TLS 1.2". For that, see [Which Cipher Suites to enable for SSL Socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23365536/608639). It shows you how to enable/disable both protocols and cipher suites.

---

> ```
> SSL_CTX_set_options(ssl_ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION | SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE);
> ```

You should also set a cipher suite list since OpenSSL includes broken/weak/wounded ciphers by default. Something like:

```
const char PREFERRED_CIPHERS[] = "HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!PSK:!SRP:!MD5:!RC4";
long res = SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ssl_ctx, PREFERRED_CIPHERS);
ASSERT(res == 1);
```

---

I *think* your final step is to ensure the self-signed certificate is trusted.

For a Java client, see [How to properly import a selfsigned certificate into Java keystore that is available to all Java applications by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11617655/608639). For an OpenSSL client, just load it up using [`SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html), see [SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations Fails with SSL_ERROR_NONE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27878816/608639).

---

***Note well***: OpenSSL prior to 1.1.0 did *not* perform hostname validation. You will have to do that yourself. If you need to perform hostname validation, then lift the code from [`cURL's url.c`](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/lib/url.c). I seem to recall looking at Daniel's code, and its very solid. You can also lift the code from [Google's CT project](https://github.com/google/certificate-transparency/blob/master/cpp/third_party/isec_partners/openssl_hostname_validation.c). I never audited it, so I don't know what its like.

There are two other checks you have to make; they are discussed at [SSL/TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: In which version(s) did Java 'used to do' that?

Comment: @EJP - 6,7 and 8. I stopped filing bug reports with Oracle for the issue because they were not fixing them between releases.

Comment: i'm testing with JDK 1.6 on mac. I know 7 & 8 were released but i don't want new bugs and incompatibilities.

Comment: @4ntoine - Oh, in that case... I don't think TLS 1.2 was supported back then. Is it even listed as an available protocol (i.e., `getSupportedProtocols()`)? If it is, then you may have problems with secure renegotiation and a few other SSL/TLS sore spots. Also see [SSLContext initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11505994/608639).

Comment: yes, "TLSv1.2" is listed in supported protocols. I will check with link above